# SwiftUI's keyboardShortcut is not working if Button has a buttonStyle

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, keyboard-shortcuts, swiftui-button

My code:

```
                Button(action: {
                    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1026)
                    isActive.toggle()
                }){
                    HStack{
                        Image(systemName: "trash")
                        Text("delete")
                    }
                }
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .font(.body)
                .keyboardShortcut("b",modifiers: [])
```

in this stage keyboardShortcut is working but when I add buttonStyle keyboardShortcut is not working
code with buttonStyle:

```
                Button(action: {
                    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1026)
                    isActive.toggle()
                }){
                    HStack{
                        Image(systemName: "trash")
                        Text("delete")
                    }
                }
                .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .font(.body)
                .keyboardShortcut("b",modifiers: [])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

works well for me on macos 12.beta, xcode 13.beta, target ios 14.7 and MacCatalyst 12. Tested on macOS 12 MacCatalyst app. What system are you using?

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            print("---> button clicked")
        }) {
            HStack{
                Image(systemName: "trash")
                Text("delete")
            }
        }
        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
        .foregroundColor(.red)
        .font(.body)
        .keyboardShortcut("b",modifiers: [])
    }
}
```

Comment: Same issue here, doesn't work. I'm on macOS 12.3, using Xcode 13.3. No Catalyst but directly building for Mac.

Comment: Created and tested a macos 12.3 **only** app, and all still works well for me.
The keyboardShortcut does click the button.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same Issue, but If I use `BorderlessButtonStyle()` instead of `PlainButtonStyle`, works for me.